# What is the derivative of $c\mapsto F(cx)$ for fixed $x$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F:\mathcal B\to \mathbb R$ be a nice functional on Banach space $\mathcal B$. Define for fixed $x\in \mathcal B$ and for $c\in \mathbb R$ the map $\phi_x:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by

$$\phi_x(c)=F(cx).$$

Is there a nice expression for $$\frac{d}{dc}\phi_x(c)?$$

The naive way to do it is $F'(cx)\cdot x$. However the derivative and the multiplication are both unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choice of derivative for $G:X \rightarrow Y$ ($X, Y$ Banach spaces)  in $x$ should be a linear map $D_xG:X \rightarrow Y$ such that
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\lVert G(x+h) -G(x)-D_xG(h)\rVert_Y}{\lVert h \rVert_X} = 0.
$$
It's called Fréchet derivative. Chain rule also applies to Fréchet-derivatives. If some $f$ is Fréchet-differentiable in $x$ and $g$ is Fréchet-differentiable in $f(x)$, then
$$
(D_x(g\circ f)(h)) = (D_{f(x)}g\circ D_xf)(h).
$$
Proof works exactly as it does in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So if $j:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is $j(c) := cx$, then you can easily calculate its Fréchet-derivative by $D_cjh =hx$. And so, for $h \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
D_c(\phi_x)(h) = D_c(F\circ j)(h) = (D_{j(c)}F\circ D_cj)(h) = (D_{cx}F(hx)) \underset{\text{linearity}}{=} (D_{j(c)}F(x))h
$$
Fréchet-derivative and normal derivative are the same in $\mathbb{R}$, so you would normally write $\phi_x'(c) = (D_{cx}F(x))$.

**Example:** If $\mathcal{B} = L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $x:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x(t):= \exp(-t^2)$ and $\displaystyle F(y) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)^2~\mathrm{d}y$, you can easily compute that
$$
D_yF(h) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 2y(t)h(t)~\mathrm{d}t
$$
for all $h \in \mathcal{B}$. Then
$$
\phi_x'(c) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 2c\exp(-t^2)\exp(-t^2)~\mathrm{d}x
$$

This example is easy enough for you to also compute it the convential way.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer - what exactly do you mean by $D_{cx}$? The Frechet derivative along $cx$?

Comment: At point $cx$, yes. If you have a differentiable function in $x$ in the usual sense $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $Df_x(h) = f'(x)h$ for the Fréchet-derivative.

Answer (score 0):

$ F'(cx) $ could refer to the Frechet or Gateaux derivative, which is a functional you can indeed apply to $x$.